# address of member structure in map file?

Tags: c++, c, linker, hardware, ld

There has been already question about this topic (notably [How to get address of some struct member in array of structures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11825970/how-to-get-address-of-some-struct-member-in-array-of-structures)).

My question is the following :
when we use `struct` to describe a hardware device, so each structure member will correspond to some registers of the hardware device - how can we be sure that each member of the structure is mapped correctly on each register of the hardware ?

The ABI of the compiler dictates the alignment of the members, the user can also makes some mistake - and the only way to be sure that the mapping is done correctly is to check at run time.
The map file (at least for GNU ld) does not provide any clue about the placement of structure members.

Would there be a way to know at compiler or link time where each structure members are located ?

Comment: You are correct, this is not possible in a portable way. You will have to rely on extensions and/or behaviour of specific compilers

Comment: This is system specific anyway. If you move the code to a totally different kind of computer, the hardware device will not be there.

Comment: absolutly agree, it depends on the (cpu,compiler). But even with the same cpu & same compiler, I would like to be sure that there is no mistake in the mapping - and I am looking for a way that could display me the map of my structure members via a Map file. But it seems that the only way is to have a piece of code that display those addresses at run time.

Comment: C is not C++ is not C, please select the language that you **currently use**

Comment: both C & C++ can be used - it depends on the project on which I am working on. Describing a hw device via a structure is a common practive in our projects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`offsetof`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/offsetof) along with, in C++, [`static_assert`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_assert).

For example, the entirely arbitrary

```
#include <cstddef>
struct iom {     // off,len
  uint32_t rx;   // +0,4
  uint32_t tx;   // +4,4
  uint64_t clk;  // +8,8
  uint16_t irq;  // +16,2
};
static_assert(offsetof(iom,rx)==0);
static_assert(offsetof(iom,tx)==4);
static_assert(offsetof(iom,clk)==8);
static_assert(offsetof(iom,irq)==16);
```

If the `static_assert` fails, for example because your compiler aligns the members to 64-bit boundaries, you need a compiler specific way to alter the alignment and padding. Eg, with gcc,

```
    } __attribute__((packed));
```

at the end of the struct definition.

---

NB. I've answered for C++17.

C++11 or 14, or C11 require an error message as the second argument to `static_assert`, although you can wrap the whole thing in a macro to compose a nice string for you.

The `offsetof` macro works in C as well.

Comment: Thanks for prompting me to check that, I didn't know.